# How do I Implement this? Can someone help me?

Tags: android

I want my share button to change to 'shared' or change color when I click on it or share a document. I want it to show the toast message and also change to reflect that the document has been shared. How do I Implement this? This is what I have.

```
const handleSubmit = () => {

    localStorage.setItem('isShared', 'true')

    Toaster.show({ message: `Successfully shared!`, intent: 'success' })

 

    if (onSubmit) onSubmit()

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

To change color on click of the  button you should use the StateListDrawable in android[to now more click on this link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable)